# Security situation along I-75 on Florida's Gulf Coast

Tags: usa, security, florida

I am talking a drive up through Florida, via Naples and up past Tampa.

Are there areas I should avoid staying in? For example neighbourhoods I should for example not rent a motel in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you have much to worry about.

While yes there are some neighborhoods, in the bigger cities like Tampa, that might not be the best place for travelers, the chances of finding a decent hotel in those areas is pretty low.  In the bigger cities the majority of areas with a choice of hotels will be either business or tourist areas and as such basically safe to visit.

You will find that many of the interchanges for I-75 have several motel choices, so if you are really concerned you could always stay there and head into the cities to visit during the day.

In rural Florida, you can stay most anywhere and not be concerned about high crime risk.

Of course a modicum of common sense, same as you would use traveling anywhere, is always a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

There are resources available online that map crime in larger metropolitan areas such as:

- [Spot Crime](http://spotcrime.com/fl/tampa)
- [Raids Online](http://www.tampagov.net/Dept_police/information_resources/Crime_Statistics/)

and and few others.  You can start reviewing them to see where particular crime you're concerned about is clustered and avoid those areas.

I have not been able to find similar statistics for the Rural areas but doesn't mean that these are not there.